# dynamic query with date criteria

Tags: liferay, criteria, dynamicquery

I am trying to implement search query using dynamic query
I created dynamic query like this

```
DynamicQuery dynamicQuery=DynamicQueryFactoryUtil.forClass(OrderSubscription.class,PortletClassLoaderUtil.getClassLoader());
DynamicQuery dynamicQueryCount=DynamicQueryFactoryUtil.forClass(OrderSubscription.class,PortletClassLoaderUtil.getClassLoader());

Criterion criterion = RestrictionsFactoryUtil.like(DBConstants.OrderSubscription.ORDERNO, StringPool.PERCENT+searchKeyword+StringPool.PERCENT);
criterion = RestrictionsFactoryUtil.or(criterion, RestrictionsFactoryUtil.like(DBConstants.OrderSubscription.STATUS, StringPool.PERCENT+searchKeyword+StringPool.PERCENT));
criterion = RestrictionsFactoryUtil.or(criterion, RestrictionsFactoryUtil.like(DBConstants.OrderSubscription.ORDERDATE, StringPool.PERCENT+searchKeyword+StringPool.PERCENT));
criterion = RestrictionsFactoryUtil.or(criterion, RestrictionsFactoryUtil.like(DBConstants.OrderSubscription.PAYMENTSTATUS, StringPool.PERCENT+searchKeyword+StringPool.PERCENT));
criterion = RestrictionsFactoryUtil.or(criterion, RestrictionsFactoryUtil.like(DBConstants.OrderSubscription.ORDERSTATUS, StringPool.PERCENT+searchKeyword+StringPool.PERCENT));
criterion = RestrictionsFactoryUtil.or(criterion, RestrictionsFactoryUtil.like(DBConstants.OrderSubscription.ORDERID, StringPool.PERCENT+searchKeyword+StringPool.PERCENT));
criterion = RestrictionsFactoryUtil.or(criterion, RestrictionsFactoryUtil.like(DBConstants.OrderSubscription.PAYMENTTRANSACTIONTYPE, StringPool.PERCENT+searchKeyword+StringPool.PERCENT));
criterion = RestrictionsFactoryUtil.or(criterion, RestrictionsFactoryUtil.like(DBConstants.OrderSubscription.STARTDATE, StringPool.PERCENT+searchKeyword+StringPool.PERCENT));
criterion = RestrictionsFactoryUtil.or(criterion, RestrictionsFactoryUtil.like(DBConstants.OrderSubscription.CANCELDATE, StringPool.PERCENT+searchKeyword+StringPool.PERCENT));

dynamicQuery.add(junctionOR);
dynamicQueryCount.add(junctionOR);

List<OrderSubscription> orders = OrderSubscriptionLocalServiceUtil.dynamicQuery(dynamicQuery, start, end);
```

Now its throwing error of casting

```
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Date
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.JdbcTimestampTypeDescriptor.unwrap(JdbcTimestampTypeDescriptor.java:42)
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.TimestampTypeDescriptor$1.doBind(TimestampTypeDescriptor.java:53)
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder.bind(BasicBinder.java:91)
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:283)
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:278)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.bindPositionalParameters(Loader.java:1873)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.bindParameterValues(Loader.java:1844)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1716)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:801)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:274)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2542)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2276)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2271)
at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:119)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1716)
at org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:347)
at com.liferay.portal.dao.orm.hibernate.DynamicQueryImpl.list(DynamicQueryImpl.java:94)
at com.liferay.portal.dao.orm.hibernate.DynamicQueryImpl.list(DynamicQueryImpl.java:88)
at com.liferay.portal.service.persistence.impl.BasePersistenceImpl.findWithDynamicQuery(BasePersistenceImpl.java:166)
... 148 more
Jan 08, 2016 6:39:51 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet ordermanagment Servlet threw exception
```

summary :

i want to get list based on searched keyword from DB
and my DB column type id datetime.

Can any one help me sort out this problem

Thanks
Ravi Darji

Comment: I think, the problem is because you are setting `String` for `Date` parameter on line `criterion = RestrictionsFactoryUtil.or(criterion, RestrictionsFactoryUtil.like(DBConstants.OrderSubscription.ORDERDATE, StringPool.PERCENT+searchKeyword+StringPool.PERCENT));` Shouldn't it be a `Date` object? If yes, then consider `STARTDATE` and  `CANCELDATE` as well.

Comment: Well, what type of `DBConstants.OrderSubscription.ORDERDATE` is actually?

Comment: it is the keyword which i getting from search field so it can not be date always.

Comment: It is `String` obviously. I just confirmed from API that method `like`'s first parameter is a `String` type.

Comment: First, try to remove lines involving date parameters and check if it works, then add condition to check if `searchKeyword` is a date string, convert it to `Date` object first, then pass to `like` method.

Comment: after removing that line of code it is working fine
but as i said search keyword is coming from search input field
and on each key up i am firing dynamic query
so can you tell me how to check that string is date or not?

Comment: Can keyword be a String date looking from user prospective?

Comment: Also, what do you have necessity to add `like` condition on `Date` columns?